Can I disable an ESLint rule inside JSX blocks, while keeping it active in the rest of file?
This is my .eslint.cjs file for React:
module.exports = {
    root: true,
    env: {browser: true, es2020: true},
    extends: [
        'eslint:recommended',
        'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
        'plugin:react-hooks/recommended',
    ],
    ignorePatterns: ['build', '.eslintrc.cjs'],
    parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
    plugins: ['react-refresh'],
    rules: {
        'comma-dangle': ['warn', 'always-multiline'],
        /// lots of others...
    },
};

It works fine, but I'd like to disable comma-dangle inside JSX. Not for the whole .tsx file... just for the JSX portions inside .tsx files.
Is it possible?

You can disable ESLint for one line with:
// eslint-disable-next-line

And for part of file:
/* eslint-disable */

alert('foo');

/* eslint-enable */

Documentation
